# Using extra and max_num in a Django formset

Tags: django

I have a formset that has no model associated with it and I want to be able to add a form to the formset once all existing forms are valid, so reading the docs, I found: "If the value of max_num is greater than the number of existing objects, up to extra additional blank forms will be added to the formset, so long as the total number of forms does not exceed max_num."(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#limiting-the-maximum-number-of-forms):

So I did this:

```
FormSet = formset_factory(SomeForm, extra=2, max_num=10)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = FormSet(data=request.POST)
    else:
        formset = FormSet()
```

and this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{{ formset }}
<input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

expecting to see 2 empty forms, where I would get extra forms if I filled out one (or 2) forms and pressed "Next". However, only 2 forms are ever shown in the template even if I have 1 or 2 valid forms.

How is this supposed to work? Am I misinterpreting the docs? Is my code wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial answer to my question: I got it to work, but I find the solution not very Django-like. I would expect this stuff to happen automatically, without the cruft below.

Anyway, I changed my view thus:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = FormSet(data=request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        clean_data = formset.cleaned_data
        if not any(not(len(f)) for f in clean_data):
            formset = FormSet(initial=clean_data)
else:
    formset = FormSet()
```

So I re-instantiated the formset using cleaned_data from the POST data and added some stuff to prevent an extra form popping up if you press "Next" while there is still an empty form.

It works, but I really don't think this should be the way to do this.